# Searching a list of integers

Tags: python, list, search, integer

I am trying to create a code where Python will generate five random numbers between zero and nine and then store them in a list. I need the program to allow the user to enter an integer and then search the list.

```
def main():
    choice = displayMenu()
    while choice != '4':
        if choice == '1':
            createList()
        elif choice == '2':
            print(createList)
        elif choice == '3':
            searchList()
        choice = displayMenu()

    print("Thanks for playing!")


def displayMenu():
    myChoice = '0'
    while myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' \
                  and myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':
         print ("""Please choose
                        1. Create a new list of 5 integers
                        2. Display the list
                        3. Search the list
                        4. Quit
                        """)
         myChoice = input("Enter option-->")

         if myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' and \
            myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4':
             print("Invalid option. Please select again.")

    return myChoice 

import random

def linearSearch(myList):
target = int(input("--->"))
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] == target:
        return i
    return -1


#This is where I need it to ask the user to give five numbers 

def createList():
    newList = []
    while True:
        try:
            num = input("Give me five numbers: ")
            num = [int(num) for num in input().split(' ')]
            print(num)
            if any([num < 0 for num in a]):
                Exception

            print("Thank you")
            break
        except:
            print("Invalid. Try again...")

    for i in range(5):
        newList.append(random.randint(0,9))
    return newList


#This is where the user should be able to search the list

def searchList():
    target = int(input("--->"))
    result = linearSearch(myList,target)
    if result == -1:
        print("Not found...")
    else:
        print("Found at", result)
```

However, once i get the user to enter the number, it won't search the list?

Comment: What version of Python do you use? (`input` works differently in 2.6 and 3.3).

Comment: Im using python 3.6!

Comment: where did you define linearSearch?

Comment: I apologize, I realize I forgot to add that, I edited it to show.

Comment: What do you mean by "search" and "won't search"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code

1. In createList function you are asking user to enter five numbers which you are not using anywhere.
2. In main function you are calling createList() but you are not storing this in any variable. I t should be something like :

   `list=createList()`
3. In main function for choice=2 you are printing function itself, instead you should do following:

   `print(list)`

Remember to declare list at the start of main function. Because if user selects choice 2 without choice 1 then there will be error.

4. You should pass list in searchList function as following:

   `def searchList(list):
       target = int(input("--->"))
       try:
            result=list.index(target)
            print("Found at", result)
       except:
            print("Not found")`

Comment: This is extremely helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`createlist()` is creating a list but searchList() is not having a reference to it.
Your `searchList()` is not taking any argument so linearSearch() does not know which list to search for the number.

`linearSearch()`,could be defined in a better way:

```
def linearSearch(myList,target):
    for i,j in enumerate(myList):
        if target == j:
            return i
        else:
            return -1
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all linearSearch is not defined anywhere. Assuming that you have defined it somewhere, you have to pass **myList** into **searchList** function.